# Return correct records with TSQL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have Statement A and Statement B.

Statement A returns 5 records and statement B returns 1 record.

**Statement A**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT    
    Outlet.cCode,
    Employee.cEmployeeNumber,
    FROM  Outlet 
    INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeOutlet.iEmployee = Employee.iID 
    WHERE cCOde = 123
```

**Statement B**

```
 Select OutletCode, RSMcode, ASMcode, FMcode from Employee_Hierarchy
 Where OutletCode = 123
```

Now just 3 of the records from Statement A must be returned with the Employee.cEmployeeNumber is either equal to RSMcode, ASMcode or FMcode......

Now if I add the following JOIN in it will just return 1 records, how do I cater for the other 2 that are still needed?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT    
        Outlet.cCode,
        Employee.cEmployeeNumber,
        FROM  Outlet 
        INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeOutlet.iEmployee = Employee.iID 
        INNER JOIN Employee_Hierarchy as EH ON EH.RSMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber and EH.OutletCode = Outlet.cCode
        WHERE Outlet.cCode = 123
```

When I add a JOIN for each RSMcode and ASMcode and FMcode it returns nothing.....

Comment: hi, is it possible to show your table schema? Anyway can you try left outer join instead of the inner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
    Outlet.cCode,
    Employee.cEmployeeNumber,
    FROM  Outlet 
    INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeOutlet.iEmployee = Employee.iID 
    INNER JOIN Employee_Hierarchy as EH ON EH.OutletCode = Outlet.cCode AND (EH.RSMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber OR EH.ASMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber OR EH.FMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber)
WHERE Outlet.cCode = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

just a guess

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
        Outlet.cCode,
        Employee.cEmployeeNumber,
        FROM  Outlet 
        INNER JOIN Employee ON EmployeeOutlet.iEmployee = Employee.iID 
        INNER JOIN Employee_Hierarchy as EH ON EH.RSMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber and EH.OutletCode = Outlet.cCode
        and EH.OutletCode = 123
```

Comment: Nope, I have tried this and it returns NO records when I do this!

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN Employee_Hierarchy as EH ON EH.RSMcode = Employee.cEmployeeNumber and outletCode = Outlet.cCode
```

change this piece of code to

```
INNER JOIN Employee_Hierarchy as EH ON EH.OutletCode = Outlet.cCode 
WHERE 
Employee.cEmployeeNumber=EH.RSMcode OR 
Employee.cEmployeeNumber=EH.ASMcode OR
Employee.cEmployeeNumber=EH.FMcode
```